# Redux states updates from another package

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have 1 react project A which I used Redux. Which I am using B (Which is another package developed by my team)

That package also has Redux in it. Whenever I am using that package in my current project, and when the redux state is updated in that package, it automatically overrides the redux state in my project too.

Basically, when the Redux state updates in the used package, it also updates the related Redux state in my project.

It is really strange but this is what happening.
Any suggestions?

TIA

My project state should not update when the package's redux state updates

#redux

Comment: In both Redux Projects using the same reducer state key & variables ? If yes then use the unique redux key to avoid the changes on your project.